# python google cloud list vm in json format

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-compute-engine

Hi I am new to google cloud ,and I want to print vm instance in json format, but `print(json.dumps(instance))` raised an error: `TypeError: Object of type Instance is not JSON serializable`.

My code is below:

```
import json

from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import compute_v1



class VM:
    def __init__(self, cred_json_path):
        self.cred_json_path = cred_json_path
        self.credentials = self.create_credentials()
        self.page_size = 500

    def create_credentials(self):
        return service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(self.cred_json_path)

    def list_vms(self):
        client = compute_v1.InstancesClient(credentials=self.credentials)
        for zone, instances in client.aggregated_list(request={"project": self.credentials.project_id, "max_results": self.page_size}):
            for instance in instances.instances:

                print(json.dumps(instance))
                return


vm = VM("/tmp/1.json")
vm.list_vms()
```

Is there any easy way to do this? I think gcp api should have some method that I can easy to achieve this, but I cannot find. Thanks for help.

Comment: Which is the type of the `instance` in the for loop ? I am going to test your function as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I know how solve the problem.

```
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToJson
MessageToJson(instance._pb)
```

This could print json format data.